# Using the Top command with ps and kill

Tags: linux, debian

for my Computing Controlled Assessment I am looking into some of the basic commands for the Linux OS Debian. For the final question I have to write a short essay on using the `top` command along with `ps` and `kill` to investigate misbehaving system. The question asks to use help from PC specialists (or just any experienced Debian users). So if anyone could give any information on how a specialist could use these commands and anything helpful in general on these commands. Remember I'm here for information and not an answer. Thanks

Comment: SO may not be the best place to post this. The community is here to help solve specific answer to questions.

Comment: yeah more of a serverfault question.  but start with trying htop instead of top.  top is deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`top` is used for displaying a list of processes, and by default, is sorted by the amount of CPU usage it's using - so in your case, it's a handy tool to see if a specific process is taking up most of the CPU usage and causing the system to run slower. It also displays the process ID (PID) as well as the user running it. Think of it like the Linux equivalent of Task Manager in Windows.

`ps` is similar to top, but instead of constantly refreshing, it spews out all of the current processes running on the server, as well as the PID (important). Usually this is used as `ps aux`, or to be more specfic you could use this with grep to search for a specific process, e.g. `ps aux | grep httpd` to display the current Apache processes running.

`kill` is used to kill process running on the system, so if you had a script on the system taking up most of the resources and you want to forcefully kill the process, you'd use `kill`. You can also use the `killall` command to kill all processes with a matching string, e.g. `killall httpd`.

The steps I'd take to investigate a misbehaving system would be to:

1) Use `top` or `ps` to locate the process taking up the most resources, and remember the process ID.

2) If I wanted to kill the process, I'd use: `kill <process ID>`.

If you need anything else clarifying or explaining - feel free to comment!

EDIT: https://serverfault.com/ - This may be the best place to post future questions like this.

Comment: Thank you! I'll give this a try :)

Answer (score 0):

Best way to learn about this commands is to read man (manual) pages. To discover information about top just type:

```
$ man top
```

in command line and enjoy. Similarly you can display man pages for most unit command line tools using:

```
$ man <command>
```